# Logging in at the checkout process empties the cart/redirects to an empty cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2

User adds a product to the cart -> Goes to checkout -> Log in into their customer account (in the checkout process).

**Expected result:** Customer is being logged in to their account with the items chosen previously.

**Actual result:** User is being redirected to an empty cart.

Using **Magento ver. 2.2.4**.

UPDATE:

Just to give a bit more information... There are no logs in regards to this issue. Also, when adding a product to cart and logging in anywhere other than checkout works fine. So it might be worth mentioning that I use OnePageCheckout by Amasty.

Comment: can you check for any custom observer on customer login that might be causing cart empty issue

Comment: or anything suspicious error/exception in logs file ?

Comment: Not sure about the observer... but there is nothing in logs :/

Comment: It only happens on checkout too ..